# In Swift, can NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject modify the input parameters?

Tags: swift, crash, nsjsonserialization

The following Swift code crashes on the last line. Two modifications will prevent it from crashing: either adding one fewer items to the original Dictionary, OR commenting out the call to dataWithJSONObject(). I've tried using the Zombies instrument to find the problem but the code crashes without triggering a reported problem in Zombies. I'm assuming something is corrupting memory. Any idea what would cause that to happen?

```
func testAppendAndSerialize() {
    var listData: [String:[String:AnyObject]] = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,AnyObject>>()
    listData["a"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["b"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["c"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["d"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["e"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["f"] = ["selected": true]
    listData["g"] = ["selected": true]

    listData["a"]!["selected"] = false // Just demonstrating mutability

    var err: NSError?
    NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(listData, options:NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)

    listData["a"]!["selected"] = true // <-- EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)
}
```

Comment: I can reproduce the problem and it definitely looks like a bug. You should file a bug report at http://bugreport.apple.com

Comment: I filed bug 19368336